# Trying to reset the cursor position in a WPF Rich Text Box control

Tags: wpf, position, richtextbox, caret

I have a WPF Rich Text Box control where I am replacing the text with new text of the same length and I simply want to get the original caret position before I replace the text, replace the text and then reset the caret position.

I think that the problem is that it uses a TextPointer that is tied to the RichTextBox and is reset when I clear the original text so that when reapply it the position has changed. What I actually want to do is to reset it to either the character position index in the original text or I am happy to deal with Lined and Columns.

I have scoured the internet for an answer to what should be a very simple problem and nothing seems to answer it. What I really want is an X/Y coordinate or anything that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GetOffsetToPosition()` and `GetPositionAtOffset()` to save the relative position of the Caret and to restore it.

In other words, assuming that the RichTextBox initializes like this:

```
    RichTextBox rtb;
    int paragraphIndex = -1;
    int indexInParagraph;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Document = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(new Run("some text some text some text."));
        rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
        // sets the caret at a specific (random) position in the paragraph:
        rtb.CaretPosition = para.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(5);
        this.Content = rtb;
    }
```

Note the three private fields in the class.

You should save the caret's paragraph index and caret index in the paragraph, before you replace the text:

```
    public void SaveCaretState()
    {
        //enumerate and get the paragraph index
        paragraphIndex = -1;
        foreach (var p in rtb.Document.Blocks)
        {
            paragraphIndex++;
            if (p == rtb.CaretPosition.Paragraph)
                break;
        }
        //get index relative to the start of the paragraph:
        indexInParagraph = rtb.CaretPosition.Paragraph.ElementStart.GetOffsetToPosition(rtb.CaretPosition);
    }
```

and restore it whenever you liked:

```
    public void RestoreCaretState(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // you might need to insure some conditions here (paragraph should exist and ...)
        Paragraph para = rtb.Document.Blocks.ElementAt(paragraphIndex) as Paragraph;
        rtb.CaretPosition = para.ElementStart.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInParagraph);
    }
```

Please note that its a simple example and there might be other `Block`s in `RichTextBox.Document`. However, the idea and implementation is not that much different.

Comment: Thanks for that and this has helped. I notice that a position considered a block as a position so when I add blocks the position of += can skip an entire block but I can figure that out. Thanks for your help.